# Value filter in pandas dataframe keeping NaN

Tags: python, pandas, filter, data-science, nan

I am trying to filter data from a dataframe which are less than a certain value. If there is no NaN then its working fine. But when there is a nan then it is ignoring the NaN value. I want to include all the time its doesn't matter its less than or bigger than the comparing value.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'index': [1, 2, 3,  4,  5,  6,   7,  8, 9],
        'value': [5, 6, 7, np.nan, 9, 3, 11, 34, 78]
    }
)

df_chunked = df[(df['index'] >= 1) & (df['index'] <= 5)]

print('df_chunked')
print(df_chunked)

df_result = df_chunked[(df_chunked['value'] < 10)]
# df_result = df_chunked[(df_chunked['value'] < 10) | (df_chunked['value'] == np.isnan(df_chunked['value']))]

print('df_result')
print(df_result)
```

[image]

In the above result 5,6,7,9 is showing. but i want also the nan there. I tried with

```
df_result = df_chunked[(df_chunked['value'] < 10) | (df_chunked['value'] == np.isnan(df_chunked['value']))]
```

But it is not working.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **not** operator: `~`

```
df_chunked[~(df_chunked['value'].ge(10))]
#df_chunked[~(df_chunked['value']>=10)] #greater or equal(the same)

   index  value
0      1    5.0
1      2    6.0
2      3    7.0
3      4    NaN
4      5    9.0
```

**why?**

Because the logical operations simply **ignore `NaN` values and take it as `False`**, always as you can see in the following data frame, then if you want to avoid using [`series.isna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) **(
avoid unnecessary additional code)** and simplify your code simply use the inverse logic with `~`

```
print(df.assign(greater_than_5 = df['value'].gt(5),
          not_greater_than_5 = df['value'].le(5)))


   index  value  greater_than_5  not_greater_than_5
0      1    5.0           False                True
1      2    6.0            True               False
2      3    7.0            True               False
3      4    NaN           False               False
4      5    9.0            True               False
5      6    3.0           False                True
6      7   11.0            True               False
7      8   34.0            True               False
8      9   78.0            True               False
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
df_result = df_chunked[(df_chunked['value'] < 10) | (df_chunked['value'].isna())]
df_result 
   index  value
0      1    5.0
1      2    6.0
2      3    7.0
3      4    NaN
4      5    9.0
```

Comment: `(df_chunked['value'].isna())` not neccesary here, see my answer

Comment: `df_chunked[~(df_chunked['value']>=10)]` also works

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define your df_result as follows:

```py
df_result = df_chunked[(df_chunked["value"] < 10) | (df_chunked["value"].isnull())]
```

That works.